# tinymce - cannot remove thin black outline from the editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

Cannot remove thin black outline from the editor. Simply - doesn't work. Outline is still there.

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#editor',
  editor_css: "tiny.css"
});
```

```css
form,
textarea,
#editor {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add code like:

```
.tox:not([dir=rtl]) {
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: left;
    outline: 0 !important;
    border: none;
}
```

Live codepen can be check over here https://codepen.io/shivani30594/pen/JQxVzv?&editable=true

Comment: `.tox:not([dir=rtl]) {border:none;}` - just this line is enough. It works. Thanks.